# SAS "ERROR: Variable has been defined as both character and numeric"

Tags: macros, format, sas

Basically I need to import multiple excel files and simply stack them. I wrote a Macro to do that, but at the end of the code where it comes to the stack part, multiple error messages appear saying:
ERROR: Variable XX has been defined as both character and numeric.
I tried to modify format in the Macro, but it doesn't work.
(I tried "format F1=DDMMYY10, F2=12.8, F7=$12")
I also need to only keep F1-F7. But log says "The DROP and KEEP statements are not supported in procedure steps in this release of the SAS System." Therefore, these statements are ignored.

Will you please take a look at my code and let me know how I should modify it?
Here's the code:

```
%LET TOTAL=4;
%LET PATH=H:\test\;

%LET INFILE1=a (1).xlsx;
%LET INFILE2=a (2).xlsx;
%LET INFILE3=a (3).xlsx;
%LET INFILE4=a (4).xlsx;

%MACRO EXCELREAD(I,INFILE);
PROC IMPORT OUT=TEST_&i
            DATAFILE="&PATH.&INFILE"
            DBMS=EXCEL REPLACE; 
     GETNAMES=NO;
     MIXED=YES;
     SCANTEXT=YES;
     USEDATE=YES;
     SCANTIME=YES;
    /*KEEP F1 F2 F3 F4 F5 F6;
    FORMAT F1=DDMMYY10, F2=12.8, F7=$12;*/
RUN;
%MEND;
%EXCELREAD(1,&INFILE1);
%EXCELREAD(2,&INFILE2);
%EXCELREAD(3,&INFILE3);
%EXCELREAD(4,&INFILE4);


data pilot_bond;
set test_1      
    test_2(firstobs=2)
    test_3(firstobs=2)
    test_4(firstobs=2)
run;
```

Here's the error message:

```
3712  data pilot_bond;
3713      set test_1
3714          test_2(firstobs=2)
3715          test_3(firstobs=2)
3716          test_4(firstobs=2)

ERROR: Variable F1 has been defined as both character and numeric.
ERROR: Variable F2 has been defined as both character and numeric.
ERROR: Variable F6 has been defined as both character and numeric.
ERROR: Variable F7 has been defined as both character and numeric.
ERROR: Variable F6 has been defined as both character and numeric.
ERROR: Variable F6 has been defined as both character and numeric.
3730  run;
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!
Sugguestions to further simplifying the code is also very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure as to how your worksheet looks, but by looking at the error it seems that the column F1 is a character value in excel, If you open excel and if you see a green marker in the FI data cell then it is a character value then ,you need to
1. export the data in **.xlsx** files using "Import" wizard first and
2. Then run the above program

This should solve the issue you have.